# In DHIS2, what is the highest number of data element that a numerator can contain to make up an indicator?

Tags: structured-data, database, dhis2

Recently, we updated the family planning dataset to collect data on 6 different age groups by clients prefered methods across all family planning acceptors (both new and continuing). So in calculating the acceptor rate, we have to add up over 228 individual data elements in the numerator to make the indicator.

We were only successful in populating  108 data elements. Anything beyond this, we were unable to save. What are not doing right? Is there a way to go around it, for instance using the sub totals instead of the individual data elements ? What is the highest number of data element that a numerator can contain to make up an indicator in DHIS2?